# Configure site exceptions list in Java 7 on a Linux machine

Tags: java, linux, security

[Site Exception List](https://www.java.com/en/download/exception_sitelist.jsp) is a new security feature since sun Java 7. It can be configured on Windows through the control panel. How do I configure it on a Linux distribution?

Comment: Search `linux  exception site list` with Google. The first result is valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check [Adding a site to the Exception Site List](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/upcoming_exception_site_list_in) and follow the steps provided there to configure Exception List on Linux.

> Linux/Solaris - Run the jcontrol command.

- Choose the Security tab.
- Click the "Manage Site List" button near the bottom.
- A new window will open.

[image]

- Click the Add button.

[image]

- Click OK. The window will close. You may see an additional prompt if
  you use an unencrypted protocol such as http or file. Choosing
  encrypted protocols defends against potential man-in-the-middle
  attacks.
- Back on the control panel, click OK to close it.
- Reload the web page on your browser to launch the RIA.

Answer (score 6):

Just run this:

```
echo 'https://asafesite.com
https://another.url
https://and.anotherone.com' > ~/.java/deployment/security/exception.sites
```